# Emacs CPerl mode: bug in indent-region

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

I edit my Perl scripts in Emacs, using `CPerl` mode. But the Emacs function `indent-region` is broken in that mode. If I have a variable:

```
my $num_elements;
```

it becomes

```
my $num_ elements;
```

It's very annoying, especially since I am used to using underscores in variable names, and I press the keyboard shortcut for `indent-region` all the time (actually, a custom `indent-whole-buffer` function based on it), it's already automatic.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I am using this Emacs:

```
GNU Emacs 21.4.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) 
  of 2007-12-10 on hs20-bc1-5.build.redhat.com
```

**UPDATE:** Actually this happens only after a `foreach` (or similar):

```
foreach my $num_elements (1,2) {}
```

becomes:

```
foreach my $num_ elements (1,2) {}
```

Comment: Could you add your version numbers?  It works in my GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.16.6).

Comment: @Svante: Okay, added it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated versions of cperl-mode are available.  The [official version](http://math.berkeley.edu/~ilya/software/emacs/) and [an unofficial version that's aware of 5.10 and Moose](http://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode).  Updating to one of those should fix your problem.

`M-x describe-variable cperl-version` will show what version of cperl-mode you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to install the latest version of cperl (although I probably won't since that sounds like an annoying thing to spend time on ...) BTW, my Emacs version does not have the command `describe-version`.

Comment: Sorry, `describe-variable`.  Installing a new copy of cperl-mode is easy.  In `~/.emacs` put `(add-to-list  'load-path "~/emacs")` and then put `cperl-mode.el` into `~/emacs`.

Comment: Thanks! You convinced me, I installed cperl 5.14, and it's fixed now.

Comment: @dehmann 5.14 is 5 years old.  Might as well use the latest else later on down the road you'll hit some other bug that's already been fixed.